# Difference in length calculation for SVG text element

Tags: svg, rust, fonts

I am creating an SVG using the `svg` crate. To properly place a border around a `<text>` element, I calculate the length of the text beforehand using the `rusttype` crate.

However, my browser (Safari) seems to render the text with a different length.

The simplified version of my SVG is here:

```svg
<svg viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g>
<path d="M105,20 L304,20 L304,77 L105,77 z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
<text font-family="Arial" font-size="12" x="110" y="57">My extremely very, very, very, long Goal</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

I do calculate the length as found suggested [here](https://gitlab.redox-os.org/redox-os/rusttype/-/blob/master/dev/examples/image.rs):

```rust
pub fn text_bounding_box(font: &Font, text: &str, size: f32) -> (u32, u32) {
    let scale = rusttype::Scale::uniform(size);
    let width = font
        .layout(text, scale, rusttype::point(0.0, 0.0))
        .last()
        .map(|g| g.pixel_bounding_box().unwrap().max.x)
        .unwrap_or(0);

    let v_metrics = font.v_metrics(scale);
    let height = (v_metrics.ascent - v_metrics.descent).ceil() + v_metrics.line_gap;

    (width as u32, height as u32)
}
```

I ensured that the used font is `Arial` in both cases (when I calculate it, and for the SVG). At least, that's what I think.

My calculation yields a length of `189px`. When inspecting the SVG with Safari, I see a width of `~213.14px`.

Any suggestions are welcome.
I found a workaround to place a `textLength` attribute in the SVG, but I would at least like to understand the discrepancy. Thanks in advance.

*Edit:*
Rendered SVG without textLength attribute:
[image: Rendered without textLength]

Rendered SVG with calculated textLength attribute:
[image: Rendered with calculated textLength]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible reasons for the discrepancies between measing text in two different libraries/engines.

- Kerning differences
- Ligature handling differences
- On-screen font renderers often adjust glyph position to better align with screen pixels. Especially for small font sizes.
- There are other potential font-specific features and variations that may be affecting rendering

Most likely is probably #3.  Try setting font size to something big (eg. 100) to see if this is the case.  You could also try experimenting with the CSS `text-rendering` property.

Comment: Thanks, sounds sensible. I checked with font size of 100. Same here: 1581px to 1777.02px. At least proportional ~11%...
From looking at the rendering (with and without textLength) it looks like the distance between the glyphs is different. Any idea here?

Comment: Using `text-rendering` only makes the text taking more width. I tried all settings.

Comment: Is it a kerning difference or a letter spacing difference?  Is it possible to post a rendering of the test string from both Safari and rusttype?

Comment: Thanks for keeping up. I don't render via rusttype, I just use it to calculate the size of the box around it. I added a rendering of the SVG with and without textLength, though.

Comment: I understand. I was interested in a rendering from rusttype, because a visual representation might provide hints as to what it is doing differently from the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I checked if it is possible to render via rusttype, but its not that easy.

Comment: You could try experimenting with combinations of one and two letters. First check that a single letter matches in both.  If they do, try two letter combinations. Eg. does "xx" match.  Then try combos that likely have kerning. Eg. "VA".  Also, have you tried asking the rusttype developer, or fling a bug there?  BTW there's no need to give me a green check if my answer hasn't solved your problem.

Comment: My question also was about an explanation about the differences. You did that. 